# SQL executing twice in IIS10 with ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, iis-10

I have a new dev/test environment that is in IIS 10 (with asp classic as api) and SQL Server 2016. Today, I noticed that some posts was doubling records in the database.
Upon further review, the IIS logs only show one request, but SQL Trace shows 2 concurrent SQL:BatchCompleted traces for every call to the database using the unsecure `cn.execute "stored_procedure 'param1'"` method, but any database call that is with a prepared statement only has one RPC:Completed hit in the trace and is performing like normal.

Our production environment has the same SQL version, but is still in IIS6, currently. I lost my dev IIS box with the same setup a couple weeks ago and hadn't noticed this before. About 90% of our API has been in use in production for over a decade without this happening, and it is not happening now.

I am a little new to IIS 10 as I have been maintaining the IIS6 environment this whole time, so perhaps I have configured something wrong, but other than enabling ASP classic and parent paths, I haven't modified much to get our legacy API running.

Sample of ASP that is causing double executions:

```
dim cn
dim dbConnectionString
dim SQL
dim rs

dbConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=srvr\instance;Database=DB;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;"
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.open dbConnectionString
cn.CommandTimeout = 0
SQL = "store_procedure_name 'paramValue'"
RS.Open SQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
Response.Write( rs(0) )
rs.Close
set rs = nothing
Response.end
```

And using an ADODB prepared statement results in normal execution.

```
 Dim cmd
 Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
    .CommandTimeout = 0
End With
```

What am I missing that has been driving me insane all day? The majority of the API uses the less secure string method (I am aware of SQL injection, etc.) as we haven't been allotted the time to refactor to prepared statements. However, All new code is written with prepared statements.

**UPDATE**

It appears something is different in SQL Native Client 11. Grabbed version 10 from SQL 2008 R3 and it is not doing the double call anymore.
`Provider=SQLNCLI10`

I guess at this point, I can continue with version sqlncli 10, but I'd love to know what is going on with sqlncli 11...

Comment: if forgot the create rs object in the problem code snippit: `set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")`

Comment: Thanks to @JoshMontgomery, we've narrowed it down to `RS.Open` creating a second call. Using `set RS = cn.Execute(SQL)` does not cause the same issue

Answer (score 1):

since you're not updating the recordset object directly, don't use

```
RS.Open SQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

but rather

set RS = cn.Execute( sql )

I've had weird problems in the past using RS.Open and only use them if I want to modify data directly in the recordset, which is an uncommon thing for me to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't help, but that is a good idea. I do use `set RS = Stmt.Execute()` in our new development code.

Comment: Actually, I take that back... I had created a second site and tested that change on the wrong one - so that stopped a second trace occurring... progress! Next question would be why is `RS.Open` causing a second call to sql and `cn.execute` is not? I can't change 60k + lines of code because of one test server.

Comment: My guess is it's a cursor related issue, try RS.Open SQL, cn, 3,, 1,if that doesn't work report back and I'll see (or someone else) can come up with something else to try

Comment: Based on production working correctly with the code as is, I started going through what is different between production and this test environment. Narrowing it down to the SQLNCLI driver, I tried version 10 from SQL 2008r3, and its working normally now. Based on our constant library, adOpenStatic is 3, adLockReadOnly is 1. The only thing I see putting the ints in directly is that it cuts out the constants include file. To be complete, I outputted those constants to the response and they are still reporting as 3 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I just wish I knew why SQLNCLI11 works different than SQLNCLI10. Haven't found much literature yet... The traces for each also looked completely different.

Comment: i don't know the exact reason, but it makes sense that when you use 2 different drivers, that you may run into some issues. anyways, glad you got it figured out :)